# Question regarding interest method during a year. $i-\delta$

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

> B and P deposits the amount $100$ in separate bank accounts.  B's account have a nominal rate convertible semiannually.  P's account has a force of interest $\delta$.  After $7.25$ years, each account has $200$.  Calculate $i-\delta$.

The following is what I tried.

Under P's account,

$$100\exp \left( \int_0^{7.25} \delta \quad dt \right) = 200$$

so we can solve for

$$\delta = \frac{\ln 2 }{7.25}$$

Which I understand.  What I am having trouble with is B's account.

I can see that for the first $7$ years under the assumption that the nominal annual rate is $i$, the initial value will be multiplied by $(1+i)^7$, but what happens for the rest $0.25$ of the year?

I've been hearing that during the year between the conversion period, usually people use simple interest to calculate the amount.  However, if we did that then $i$ will be calculated as

$$100(1+i)^7(1+0.25i)=200$$

which is beyond my level because I cannot use a graphing calculator to solve this problem.

Even assuming that since the conversion occurs $3$ months later and I am able to find that

$$100(1+i)^7=200$$

then

$$i = \sqrt[7]{2}-1$$

my $i- \delta$ does not equal $0.23\%$, which is supposedly the correct answer.

I tried using $i^{(2)}$ where

$$100(1+ \frac{(i^{(2)}}{2})^2=200$$

but $i^{(2)}-\delta$ was not the answer either.

Cal I have some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would calculate $C_{7.5}=100\cdot \left(1+\frac{i}{2}\right)^{14.5}=200$

$\text{\$}100$ are compounded with the interest rate of $\frac{i}{2}$ in the first six months. Then this amount of money is compounded for another 6 months with the interest rate of $\frac{i}{2}$. It goes on till the 15th half year.

The general formula is $C_n=C_0\cdot\left(1+\frac{i}{m}\right)^{m \cdot n}$

Comment: Unfortunately that does not give me the answer.  Besides, if you are counting the last conversion with $i^{(2)} \over 2$ there should be 29 conversions.

Comment: I misscalculated. I will make an edit. Try $m \cdot n=2\cdot 7.25=14.5$ The annual rate is converted to SEMIannual rate. You will get the suggested answer.

Comment: Great.  The only problem that I am having is that when a conversion is yet due, do we traditionally use compound interest or simple interest? Because I hear each cases and I have no idea which one to pick.

Comment: Could you give me a small example ? I don´t understand your question, sorry :)

Comment: It's more of a question regarding in finance, lending money to someone in a short period of time (usually less than 1 yr) results in simple interest rather that compound interest because simple interest earns more money.  But in this case for the period where 6 months have not passed, we used compound interest...  Sorry, I'm still a newby to this so I cannot make a good example.

Comment: In general it depends on the time when interest are payed. If  they are payed semianually (by contract) and you have the money 4 months in the account the factor is $\left(1+\frac{i}{2} \right) ^{4/6}$. In the case of 8 months the factor is $\left(1+\frac{i}{2} \right) ^{8/6}$